# How to use iterator in a function where a vector is passed by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator, pass-by-reference

For example here is the function:

```
void process(const vector<MyItem> & list){
    vector<MyItem>::iterator iter;
    ...
}
```

However it won't compile. 
How can I fix this?
Many thanks!

Comment: Also when you report an error it's helpful to include the error in your question

Comment: `var iter = begin(list)` should already work

Answer (score 1):

You need `const_iterator` as you're taking a `const &`:

```
void process(const vector<MyItem> & list){
    vector<MyItem>::const_iterator iter;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `auto` and a function that gets an iterator from that vector (or a function in `<algorithm>`, that returns one, e.g. `std::find`):

```
void process(const vector<MyItem> & list){
    auto begin = list.begin();
    auto end = list.end()
    ...
}
```

This would make sure you always get the correct type, whatever the parameter type (here, the `const` actually means you need a `const_iterator`).